# Maven ComparableVersion contains a bug of "Load of known null value"

Tags: maven, findbugs

https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.java

The SpotBugs found this Load of known null value:

```
Load of known null value in package.ComparableVersion$ListItem.compareTo(ComparableVersion$Item) [package.ComparableVersion$ListItem] At ComparableVersion.java:[line 513] NP_LOAD_OF_KNOWN_NULL_VALUE
```

in the line of

```
int result = l == null ? (r == null ? 0 : -1 * r.compareTo(l))
                                 : l.compareTo(r);
```

Environment:

- Tryied both Windows command line and Eclipse
- spotbugs-maven-plugin version: tried both 3.1.6 and 3.1.12
- Maven version: 3.5.3
- Java version: 1.8.0_171

May I ask how to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: The null are checked...have you checked the unit tests https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-artifact/src/test/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersionTest.java furthermore have you checked the integration tests if there a condition might not be covered? https://maven.apache.org/core-its/index.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Hi, thanks for your reply! I did not run any tests as I have not made any change on the source code. I simplely put the Version.java into the package and trying to build. Then I got this: "Load of known null value in [package].ComparableVersion$ListItem.compareTo(ComparableVersion$Item) [eventhub.deploy.ComparableVersion$ListItem] At ComparableVersion.java:[line 513] NP_LOAD_OF_KNOWN_NULL_VALUE".  Looking forward to your reply and thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I know that you can't make any change on Apache Maven, cause you are not a committer. The NULL values are there ...the question is: Is there any condition which is not covered by a test? I have my doubts about that but that does not mean there could be a leak of testing...I recommend to use the unit tests and also the integration test..If you find parts which are not covered please create an issue in JIRA http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG and describe it...

Comment: BTW: This code works for about 9-10 years..since [Maven 3.0](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)?